# renaming a Yeoman generator

Tags: yeoman, yeoman-generator

I installed a custom Yeoman generator and am attempting to duplicate it and rename it for other uses. However, the new generator doesn't seem to get installed.

I tried renaming the generator name in package.json and running `npm install` and `npm link`, but still don't see the new generator when I type `yo --help`.

Any ideas on what I might be missing?

Comment: Did you try renaming the folder too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did try renaming the folder - thanks.

Found out what my particular issue was.. I stumbled across another post saying that the issue could result if `NODE_PATH` is empty.

Once I ran the following it worked for me:

export NODE_PATH="$HOME/.nvm/`nvm current | sed -e 's/current\:[[:space:]]*//'`/lib/node_modules"